# Retrieving facebook fanpage post via PHP sdk as a user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to build an app where users who are following(those that have liked the fan page) a particular facebook fan page can comment on posts found on the fan page. I get no error when i use the access token of an admin user of the fan page to retrieve posts, but when i use a non admin user(at least someone who has liked the page), i get the error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

I store each user's details in a database including his/her access token when they login and accepted the necessary permission such as **publish_stream, read_stream, offline_access, manage_pages**

My question is this, is it possible that i can retrieve the post with other user's access token as it seems that it is only the access token from the admin user that allows me to retrieve posts?

Answer (score 0):

For reading the feed of a page, you only need an app access token:

```
$app_accesstoken = APP-ID . '|' . APP-SECRET;
```

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

> "an app or user access token for public and non-demographically
>   restricted pages"

Btw, "offline_access" is deprecated since months and will be deactivated soon.